# Google Chrome won't load image but other browsers will. Image url bring up a square

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, browser

This is the second time I ran into this issue. I put a png image on my website here freshmindmusic.com/citytheking . It loads in other browsers but Chrome doesn't load it even on my cell phone. When I go directly to the link for the photo, chrome knows it exist but shows a box instead. I attached a screen shot. I also re-uploaded the image and changed its name. Is it just a Chrome issue? Is there something I should avoid?

[image]

Comment: In Firefox when I go to http://freshmindmusic.com/images/help.png I get "The image “http://freshmindmusic.com/images/help.png” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

Answer (score 0):

The `help.png` image you have doesn't appear to be a valid PNG. I seem to get a response in Chrome that shows content, but it doesn't get rendered correctly.

```
Content-Length:63825 
Content-Type:image/png
```

You need to make sure that the image type matches the file extension. If you saved the image as a JPG, and then renamed the extension, for example, this will cause the server to respond with the wrong MIME type.

Makes sure you export the image from your image editor as a PNG image type and re-upload.

Comment: magically it works now. That's not the first time I had that issue though. Next time it happens I'll post here. The image was loading in Safari and Firefox but giving me that box in chrome

Comment: @CitytheKing Clear your cache, it loads fine for me now. It wasn't working in any browser for me until you re-exported and uploaded the image.

Comment: @GideonPyzer what about sprite images?
I'm facing the same issue only on CHROME but from time to time works fine... then I refresh the page and the issue is back!!!
It happens on Nexus 6P mobile (using CHROME Dev) and all desktop/laptop devices not on iPhones though...

Answer (score 0):

This answered my question
https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=16682

There seems to be multiple formats for uploading files via ftp, but images must be set to Binary or they will get corrupted. I haven't figured out how to set it this way in Dreamweaver but I did notice that if you try to replace an image through Dreamweaver's FTP with a file with the same name, it gets corrupted and the white square will show as well.